# segmentation fault on memcpy

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, memcpy

the full code is in

http://docs.google.com/file/d/0B09y_TWqTtwlaHNjdjYybHVIcjA/edit?usp=sharing

```
    char data[]="just for a try";
    u_char *packet=(u_char *)malloc(28+sizeof(data));
     ...
     ...


    u_char *udp_data=(u_char *)malloc(8+sizeof(data));
    if(udp_data == NULL )
            perror("allocating space for udp_data fails\n");
    memcpy(udp_data, &udp, sizeof(udp));
    memcpy(udp_data+8, data, sizeof(data));
    udp.check = in_cksum_udp(ip.ip_src.s_addr, ip.ip_dst.s_addr, (unsigned short *)udp_data, sizeof(udp)+sizeof(data)); // if I comment this line, no segmentation fault!
    free(udp_data);
    udp_data=NULL;

    // I get segmentation fault on the next line:
    memcpy(packet + 20, &udp, sizeof(udp));
```

the problem is the cksum_udp() function
the error is

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400a2b in run (arg=0x0) at raw_udp_client.c:115
115     memcpy(packet + 20, &udp, sizeof(udp));
```

the core dump
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B09y_TWqTtwldFI5UGdfc01RU28/edit?usp=sharing
before the in_cksum_udp()

```
ip = {ip_hl = 5, ip_v = 4, ip_tos = 0 '\000', ip_len = 10752, ip_id = 0, 
ip_off = 0, ip_ttl = 64 '@', ip_p = 17 '\021', ip_sum = 32808, ip_src = {
s_addr = 1825136778}, ip_dst = {s_addr = 376725642}}
udp = {source = 51377, dest = 125, len = 5632, check = 0}
sd = 0
on = 1
sin = {sin_family = 1, sin_port = 0, sin_addr = {s_addr = 0}, 
sin_zero = "ݲ\360\000\000\000\000"}
packet = 0x602010 "E"
data = "I'm not here!"
udp_data = 0x602050 "\261\310}"
```

after the in_cksum_udp()

```
ip = {ip_hl = 0, ip_v = 0, ip_tos = 0 '\000', ip_len = 0, ip_id = 0, 
ip_off = 0, ip_ttl = 0 '\000', ip_p = 0 '\000', ip_sum = 0, ip_src = {
  s_addr = 0}, ip_dst = {s_addr = 0}}
udp = {source = 0, dest = 0, len = 0, check = 4842}
sd = 0
on = 0
sin = {sin_family = 0, sin_port = 0, sin_addr = {s_addr = 0}, 
sin_zero = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"}
packet = 0x0
data = '\000' <repeats 13 times>
udp_data = 0x0
```

the in_cksum_udp() function is as below, I don't see any problems:

```
struct psd_udp {
    struct in_addr src;
    struct in_addr dst;
    unsigned char pad;
    unsigned char proto;
    unsigned short udp_len;
    struct udphdr udp;
};

unsigned short in_cksum(unsigned short *addr, int len)
{
    int nleft = len;
    int sum = 0;
    unsigned short *w = addr;
    unsigned short answer = 0;

    while (nleft > 1) {
            sum += *w++;
            nleft -= 2;
    }

    if (nleft == 1) {
            *(unsigned char *) (&answer) = *(unsigned char *) w;
            sum += answer;
    }

    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xFFFF);
    sum += (sum >> 16);
    answer = ~sum;
    return (answer);
}


unsigned short in_cksum_udp(int src, int dst, unsigned short *addr, int len)
{
    struct psd_udp buf;

    memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    buf.src.s_addr = src;
    buf.dst.s_addr = dst;
    buf.pad = 0;
    buf.proto = IPPROTO_UDP;
    buf.udp_len = htons(len);
    memcpy(&(buf.udp), addr, len);
    return in_cksum((unsigned short *)&buf, 12 + len);
}
```

it seems the function has nothing to do with the memory pointed by the pointer packet
what are potential problems?

Comment: hi, I have add those you required, thanks!

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you *debugged* this. By your own analysis the call to `in_cksum_udp` is corrupting your `packet` memory. Stepping through the code to see *how* / *when* would have saved you a ton of time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In function `in_csum_udp`, this line:

```
memcpy(&(buf.udp), addr, len);
```

is copying `sizeof(struct udphdr) + sizeof(data)` bytes to `buf.udp`, that is a `struct udphdr`. Since this is the last element of the structure, the stack gets corrupted.

Comment: +1 Considering the quagmire of code you weeded through to get this, I would upvote it again if I could. There are plenty of things to take issue with in this code, but none-the-less this is *very* likely the correct answer for this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another bug (reading outside buffer). This is probably not the one causing the memory corruption.

You are sending `len` bytes into `in_cksum`.
`in_cksum` thinks it got `len` `short`s.

Comment: this is fine, the function carefully deals with the `len`